How to fix C# Warning CA1416 in UWP using Visual Studio
I have a project with min version Windows 10, version 1809 (10.0; Build 17763) and I get thousands of warnings:
This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'ValueSet.this[string]' is only supported on: 'Windows' 10.0.10240.0 and later. 

I read documentation, it suggests using:
[UnsupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows10.0.17763")]

I can't use it because:
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnsupportedOSPlatformAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnsupportedOSPlatform' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)

How to fix this and why do I get a warning message if the version is higher than 10.0.10240.0?

Do you have a using directive for those attributes? using System.Runtime.Versioning; I believe...

Yes. When I choose System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform the warning appears:
"Indicates that an API is supported for a specified platform or operating system. If a version is specified, the API cannot be called from an earlier version. Multiple attributes can be applied to indicate support on multiple operating systems.
Project 1 - No Available
Project 2 - Not Available
Project 3 - Available
"

I figured out, because I have multiple project with different frameworks and I share cs files between them, I can't use directly [SupportedOSPlatform("windows10.0.17763")].
I must specify for which framework rule is:
#if NET
        [System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform("windows10.0.17763")]
#endif


"I figured out, because I have multiple project with different frameworks and I share cs files between them" - any time you ask a question, if you're in an unusual context like this (sharing .cs files between projects), it's really important that you provide all the relevant context. There's no way anyone other than you could have provided this answer, because you didn't provide sufficient information in the question. (Ideally, provide a [mcve] to start with - coming up with that would probably have solved the problem for you in the first place.)

@JonSkeet Yes, but it wasn't obvious at all because the project was selected UWP and the notification was still displayed, accordingly it misled me

And that's where taking the time to try to reproduce it in a minimal example would have guided you.
